# XStream private attributes in Java

Tags: java, xstream

How does XStream gets my object values since they are private?

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String n) {
        name = n;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XStream stream = new XStream();

        Person p = new Person("Joe");
        String xml = stream.toXML(p);
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
}
```

and how do i highlight and indent my code in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does XStream gets my object values
>   since they are private?

It uses [reflection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html). See the [Converter listing](http://x-stream.github.io/converters.html) for details on how XStream convers various java types

> How do i highlight and indent my code
>   in stackoverflow?

Highlight the text and press the code button that looks like 101010

Answer (score 1):

I don't know XStream, but they sure use the reflection API where you can disable the accessors (public, private, ...).

Answer (score 1):

With API reflection. You can get any field of a [class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) with ['getDeclaredField'](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)) method, and then get the field's [value](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

They do it by reflection. This way you can access even private members. For examples, look [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).